# SpriteKit change Image after swipe gesture

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to code a game. I got an object, that can jump and slide.
I want to hold the animation of 'run' while jumping, but while sliding, I want to change the image. My problem: the image won't show off , if I just change the image to 'slide7'.
Nothing happens.
The slide animation should appear only for about 4 seconds, than go again into the run animation. Any suggestions?

My Code :

```
-(void)Mensch{

SKTexture * MenschTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Mensch1"];
MenschTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKTexture * MenschTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Mensch2"];
MenschTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

SKAction * Run = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[MenschTexture1, MenschTexture2] timePerFrame:0.4]];

Mensch = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:MenschTexture1];
Mensch.size = CGSizeMake(45, 45);
Mensch.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 5, Boden.position.y + 73);
Mensch.zPosition = 2;

Mensch.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:Mensch.size];
Mensch.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
Mensch.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
Mensch.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
Mensch.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
Mensch.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);

[Mensch runAction:Run];
[self addChild:Mensch];

}


- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizerDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeDown:)];
recognizerDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizerDown];
}


-(void)handleSwipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

[Mensch removeAllActions];

Mensch = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"slide7.png"];

NSLog(@"Slide");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *replacing* the `Mensch` object. More specifically, you are replacing the *pointer* you have to the object, but that doesn't stop it from being displayed in the scene.

You can either:

- Replace the SKTexture inside the sprite, which should be displayed immediately. This means `Mensch.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"slide7.png"];`
- Replace the Sprite. This entails removing the current sprite (`[sprite removeFromParent]`) and adding the new one (`[self addChild:newSprite]`).

I think you want the first one, since you don't have to recreate the Mensch object.

Might I add that you are performing a lot of Mensch-specific logic in this object? It would be better (from an Object Oriented standpoint) to move this creation code to an SKSpriteNode subclass Mensch.

```
@interface Mensch : SKSpriteNode

- (void) displayRunAnimation;
- (void) displaySlideAnimation;

@end

@implementation : Mensch 

- (instancetype) init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    // your initialization code here, including physics body setup

    [self displayRunAnimation];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) displayRunAnimation {
  SKTexture * MenschTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Mensch1"];
  MenschTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
  SKTexture * MenschTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Mensch2"];
  MenschTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

  SKAction * Run = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[MenschTexture1, MenschTexture2] timePerFrame:0.4]];
  // if you plan to call this often, you want to cache this SKAction, since creating it over and over is a waste of resources

  [self runAction:Run];
}

- (void) displaySlideAnimation {
  [self removeAllActions];
  self.texture  = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"slide7.png"];
  NSLog(@"Slide");

  // re-start the runAnimation after a time interval
  [self performSelector:@selector(displayRunAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but I wanted to show the new slide texture for about  4 seconds, until it goes again into the run animation. How can i code that?

Comment: Ok, I've added a call in the displaySlideAnimation method (`performSelector:@selector(displayRunAnimation)`.